# How to fetch a GMail message using GMail URL Hash in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, imap, gmail-imap

I am using Zend Framework for fetching GMail messages.
I have been able to authenticate and fetch all the messages using the zend framework using following code:

```
$storage = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap($imap);

for ($i = 1; $i <= $storage->countMessages() && $i <=10; $i++ ){ 
    echo htmlentities($storage->getMessage($i)->subject);
    echo $storage->getMessage($i)->getContent();
}
```

But I want to fetch mail using the hash which usually appears in the GMail URL when we read a message. For example in following URL:

https://mail.google.com/mail/?shva=1#inbox/137261701dcae0a6
The part after the last slash is the hash **(137261701dcae0a6)** which I suppose is in hex.
How can I use this hash to fetch the message using Zend Framework? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google link you provided (https://mail.google.com/mail/?shva=1#inbox/137261701dcae0a6) points to the whole conversation (entire thread).

137261701dcae0a6 is Gmail's thread-id in hex.

It is possible to use X-GM-THRID Gmail's IMAP extension to search for messages in this thread.

I don't know Zend, so I can't help you with the code, but IMAP communication looks as follows:

```
C: 20eeec4bb07a44be UID SEARCH X-GM-THRID 1401511523692802395
S: * SEARCH 13622
S: 20eeec4bb07a44be OK SEARCH completed (Success)
```

Comment: I tried your solution right after performing Authentication, but the response returned from server is **"Bad Search Not allowed now"**. I can use XLIST command using Zend Framework API but I am unable to perform search. I have also read in Gmail's IMap documentation that they use their custom IMAP extensions. How can one use these custom imap extensions in a generic IMAP API and are they related to what I am trying to do. Also one more thing would you please clarify, What is this "20eeec4bb07a44be" string which you have prepended to the imap command.

Comment: Have you selected a folder first?

Comment: 20eeec4bb07a44be is a random command id, it's required by IMAP

Comment: Thanks @pawel-lesnikowski, not selecting the folder was the problem. Got it rectified now :)
Also thanks for clarifying about the random command id